# Convergence of 1/2^(1+infinitesimal)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, nonstandard-analysis

If $a$ is an infinitesimal or a non-standard number or a number strictly larger then 0 and smaller then all positive real numbers. What is

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{1+a}} $

$\lim_{x\to \infty} (1+a)^x$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until kermit says what he means, we can only speculate.

Suppose $F$ is an ordered field, strictly larger than $\mathbb R$.  Then there is an element $a \in F$ such that: $a>0$ but $a<r$ for all real $r>0$.  Equivalently: $a>0$ but $a<1/n\;$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.  (Of course $\mathbb R$ contains a subset we naturally call $\mathbb N$.)  I will consider a question in the same vein as kermit's questions, but--I think--more elementary:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} xa$$

Since things like this are not conventionally defined in $F$, but only in $\mathbb R$, we will have to say what it means.  There is more than one possibility.  Here is one:

(1)  Let $b \in F$.  We say $\lim_{x\to \infty} xa = b$ iff for every positive $\epsilon \in F$, there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n \ge N$, then $|na-b|<\epsilon$.  If there is such an element $b$, then we say $\lim_{x\to\infty} xa$ exists.

(1')  We say $\lim_{x\to \infty} xa = \infty$ iff for every $k \in F$, 
there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n \ge N$, then $na > k$.

Here is another:

(2)  Let $b \in F$.  We say $\lim_{x\to \infty} xa = b$ iff for every positive $\epsilon \in F$, there exists $X \in F$ such that for all $x \in F$, if $x \ge X$, then $|xa-b|<\epsilon$.  If there is such an element $b$, then we say $\lim_{x\to\infty} xa$ exists.

(2')  We say $\lim_{x\to \infty} xa = \infty$ iff for every $k \in F$, 
there exists $X \in F$ such that for all $x \in F$, if $x \ge X$, then $xa > k$.

I numbered them (1) and (2) for reference, but there are still more possibilities...

Comment: With these definitions ... (1) $\lim_{x\to \infty} xa$ does not exist.  (1') $\lim_{x\to \infty} xa = \infty$ is false.  (2) $\lim_{x\to \infty} xa$ does not exist.  (2') $\lim_{x\to \infty} xa = \infty$ is true.

Comment: Given that he used the word 'non-standard' and the calculus-oriented questions, I think it would be a reasonable bet that he's asking (or intends to ask) about some version of the hyperreals, rather than some arbitrary ordered field containing $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 6):

By the transfer principle, any theorem of standard analysis is a theorem of non-standard analysis.

For example, $\lim_{x \to +\infty} b^x = +\infty$ when $b > 1$ is a theorem of standard analysis. Thus, its transfer is a theorem of non-standard analysis. Since $1+a > 1$, we have $\lim_{x \to +\infty} (1+a)^x = +\infty$.

Of course, if $H$ is a positive transfinite number, then $\lim_{x \to H} (1+a)^x$ is not $+\infty$, it is $(1+a)^H$. This value may or may not be transfinite, depending on whether $H$ is large enough (This is closely related to indeterminate forms), But it is definitely smaller than $+\infty$.

The same principle applies to your other examples.

EDIT: with the update (and since Kermit seems to want more comment), we know that $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} 1/n^{1+a} = \zeta(1+a)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a = +\infty$ for all $a > 0$. These statements remain true in the non-standard model.

Comment: Perhaps the OP should say what he means by those symbols involving $\infty$ in his case.

Comment: It would help. I deliberately talked about both the extended (hyper)real $+\infty$ and an ordinary transfinite hyperreal $H$ just in case the OP is mixing the two up. (and to illustrate that even though $H$ is transfinite, it's just an ordinary hyperreal and so you can do things as one would ordinarily do).

Comment: Sorry, does the first sum as of now converge, and to a standard or nonstandard number?

Comment: What does $\zeta(1+a)$ mean, when $a$ is infinitesimal?

Comment: kermit: before we can answer, you will need to say what it means.

Comment: When $a$ is infinitesmial, we have $$\zeta(1+a) = \frac{1}{a} + \gamma - \gamma (1)   a + \frac{\gamma (2)}{2}   a^{2} - \frac{\gamma (3)}{6}   a^{3} + \frac{\gamma (4)}{24}   a^{4} - \frac{\gamma (5)}{120}   a^{5} + \operatorname{O} \bigl(a^{6}\bigr)$$ where $$\gamma(n) = \lim_{m\to\infty} \left(\sum_{k = 1}^{m} \frac{\operatorname{ln} (k)^{n}}{k} - \frac{\operatorname{ln} (m)^{(n + 1)}}{n + 1}\right)$$

Comment: @Gerry: This is what the transfer principle is good for! Since $\zeta$ is a standard function on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{1\}$, its transfer is an extension to be defined on ${}^\star \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 1 \}$. Another way of putting it is that the transfer principle ensures everything we do to construct $\zeta$ in the standard case still works in the non-standard case -- e.g. the familiar infinite series formula for real part $> 1$ still works.